# BeautifulSoup: Scrapear celda a celda

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Intento explicar mi situación por si alguien puede echarme una mano. Estoy intentando extraer los datos de una tabla con la siguiente estructura:

Equipo 1 - Resultado - Equipo 2 - Minuto primer gol

Es una tabla de resultados de partidos de fútbol y hay unos 10 partidos por tabla y una tabla por cada jornada.

Para ello estoy intentando web scraping con BeautifulSoup en Python. Aunque he avanzado bastante, me encuentro con un problema. Me gustaría generar un código que fuese iterando dato a dato cada fila de la tabla y me vaya sacando cada dato a una lista de modo que tuviese, por ejemplo:

```
Lista Equipo 1: Real Madrid, Barcelona
Lista resultados: 1-0, 1-0
Lista Equipo 2: Atlético Madrid, Sevilla
Lista Minutos primer gol: 17', 64'
```

Cuando ya tuviese las listas, mi intención es hacer un dataframe completo con todos los datos extraídos. Ahora bien, me encuentro con el siguiente problema: los partidos que acaban 0-0. Esto implica que en la columna Minuto primer gol no hay ningún y no me extrae nada, por lo que no puedo 'rellenar' ese valor de ningún modo en mi dataframe y me encuentro con un error. Por seguir con el ejemplo anterior, imaginad que el segundo partido ha acabado 0-0 y que en la 'Lista Minutos primer gol' sólo aparece un dato (17').

En mi mente la solución pasaría por crear un bucle que tomase los datos celda por celda y poner una condición en 'Resultado' que si es 0-0 a la lista de Minutos primero gol se añadiese un valor por ejemplo 'Sin goles'.

Este es el código que estoy utilizando. Os pego solo la parte en la que creo el bucle:

```
def extraer():

page = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

resultados = page.find('table', class_= 'matches')

for resultado in resultados:
    equipo1 = resultado.find_all('td', class_='team-a')
    equipo1 = [x.text.strip() for x in equipo1]
    equipo2 = resultado.find_all('td', class_='team-b')
    equipo2 = [x.text.strip() for x in equipo2]
    marcador = resultado.find_all('td', class_='score-time')
    marcador = [x.text.strip() for x in marcador]
    minuto = resultado.find_all('td', class_='first-event')
    minuto = [x.text.strip() for x in minuto]
    equipos1.append(equipo1)
    equipos2.append(equipo1)
    marcadores.append(marcador)
    minutos.append(minuto)
```

Me he intentado explicar lo mejor posible, pero si queda alguna duda, puedo intentar ser más concreto. Si alguien puede echarme un cable se lo agradezco de antemano. Un saludo!

Comment: Por qué no utilizas el método [`read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html)? te va a simplificar muchísimo el proceso

Comment: Gracias, César. Era una opción que me planteaba pero me salta el error Forbidden 403. Además hay otro problema que no lo he mencionado en mi explicación por simplificar: para conseguir el 'Minuto del gol' tengo que pulsar un botón (lo tengo automatizado con Selenium) que me despliega otra tabla de donde obtengo este dato. Por eso creo que read_html podría no servirme (a no ser que haya algo que me solucionase esta otra situación y el error 403). Gracias de nuevo y a ver si logramos sacarlo. Un saludo

Comment: no tienes por qué hacer read_html directamente con el string html que recuperes con selenium, no tienes por qué hacerlo atacando a una url. Es decir, puedes ejecutar tus scripts en selenium y luego capturar la etiqueta <table> y leer con read_html. Con un ejemplo más completo se podría dar más detalle, pero la idea es pillar el driver.page_source y leerlo directamente con pandas